# Relation between two tables and show query result

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I want geting records from database and set them to a specific category taken earlier. I have this class and methods:

```
<?php
    class CategoryForum{
        private $dbHandler;

        public function __construct($db){
            $this->dbHandler = $db;
        }
        public function getCategories(){
            $rowCategory = $this->dbHandler->prepare("SELECT * FROM `category`");
            if($rowCategory->execute() == false){
                print_r($rowCategory->errorInfo());
                return false;
                }else{
                return $rowCategory->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public function getForum(){
            $rowForum = $this->dbHandler->prepare("SELECT `subject`, category.id FROM category, forum WHERE category.id = forum.id_category"); 
            if($rowForum->execute() == false){
                print_r($rowForum->errorInfo());
                return false;
                }else{
                return $rowForum->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I wrote this on the basis that:
https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP/Relacje_i_indeksy

When I execute this query included in **getForum** method, my eyes will be released on this list(becouse I geting this in ):

Screen:

[List category and forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPkCm.png)

How to make the relation between the two tables? Can you help me?

Comment: Are you able to do the join in your database query?  That's the better option.  Or must you do the grouping in php ?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `category` 
INNER JOIN `forum` 
ON `category`.`id` = `forum`.`id_category`
```

If you want to only select specific records from both tables:

```
SELECT `category`.`id`, 
       `category`.`foo`, 
       `forum`.`bar`
FROM `category` 
INNER JOIN `forum` 
ON `category`.`id` = `forum`.`id_category`
```

You may get an error that `id` is ambiguous if you have an id primary key in forums, in which case you can just give category.id an alias.

```
SELECT `category`.`id` AS categoryID,
...
```